# React Dropzone Different File Type Requirements

Tags: reactjs, dropzone

Is there a way to do validation based off the accepted file types? For example I want to accept a PNG/JPG but it can only be so wide, I want to accept a PDF also but that can only be so large.

```
<DropZoneArea
     acceptedfiles= ['image/*','application/pdf']
     onChange={setFile}
     onDrop={ //Some validation in here then reject somehow?}
/>
```

Maybe there is another way I can do this besides using OnDrop, but seems to be more complicated then I think.

Comment: Is this [material-ui-dropzone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-dropzone)  the lib you are using ?

Comment: @keikai Yes sorry left that out. Using it with Hooks